# git push origin master not working in Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, repository, command-line-interface

My mate and I are working using `GitHub` together. 
My mate who uses window 10 and ubuntu seems to have an issue pushing it from the local repository to master repository.

After run `git commit -m` on the local side, to send the changes to the remote, we run

```
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

to see no changes/updates on the repository. Identical lines of CLI commands works on Windows but no luck in Ubuntu.
Does anyone go through the same issue?

Comment: run `git remote -v` to see which repository you are trying to push/fetch

Comment: it appears <br> origin https://github.com/user1/repo name (fetch)
origin https://github.com/user1/repo name.git (push)
pair https://github.com/user2/repo name(fetch)
pair https://github.com/user2/repo name(push) @Khodabakhsh Mac or windows bring the same results. It's when pushing in ubuntu that does not work

Comment: It's not really dependent on which platform you are on. are you sure you had staged files and then you ran `git commit`?

Comment: You can check if you have staged/unstaged files using `git status`

Comment: As described above, Same lines of CLI commands work as fine on my mac or his Windows 10 but not in Ubuntu. Only possible reason we can think of is the ubuntu conflicting with the system somehow.  @Khodabakhsh

Answer (score 0):

Though not impossible, it is *very* unlikely that your issue has anything to do with the OS.

In order to find what is going on, I would start checking the following:

- `git remote -v` - do both systems have the same remotes?
- `git log --oneline` - do both systems have the same log? Does `HEAD` point to the same commit / branch?

My best guess would be that you pushed your commit from one system, then pulled the commit from the over, so when you try to push it again, it's already there.